# What are the some dynamic Sanskrit shlokas for Lord Shiva?

Tags: scripture, shiva, shiva-purana

I have read a shloka for Lord Vishnu - ugram veeram mahavishnum jwalantam sarvato mukham, nrisingham bhishanam bhadram mrityur mrityurnamamyaham. 
Can anyone will provide me same types of dynamic (or energetic) Sanskrit shlokas related to Lord Shiva?

Comment: Dynamic in what sense? All Shiva stotras will give energy .. Are you looking for something like the Tandava Stotram?

Comment: Like the above Sanskrit shloka of Vishnu & like two or four liners. Not so long. @Rickross

Comment: What is the type of the Shloka you shared of Lord Vishnu ? Otherwise it is difficult for anyone to find similar shloka.

Comment: The zeal and passion in Shiva Tandava Stotram is mind blowing.

Comment: None of the Slokas given in the accepted answer are dynamic. But yet you have accepted it. If you need simply Slokas then there are plenty of them but you asked for "dynamic" ones whatever that means. The Sloka given in ur Q looks "dynamic" to u because Narasimha is a ferocious (Ugra) form of Lord Vishnu. Since Shiva is a benign deity, similar verses are unlikely to be found for him. You need to look for angry forms of Lord Shiva like Krodha Bhairava etc. @aniketkumarsingh

Comment: @Triyugi Narayan Mani please suggest something.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good mantras  in [**Mahabharata**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b112.htm)-Shanti - Parva-Moksha Dharma Parva - In the chapter related to Daksha Yajna.   Daksha praised Lord Shiva with 180 mantras after Lord Shiva destroyed his Ashwamedha Yajna to pacify him. The above mantra is a similar type of  mantra you want where   fierce as well as peaceful aspect of   Lord Shiva is adored.

> अघोरघोररूपाय घोरघोरतराय च |
>  नमः शिवाय शान्ताय नमः शान्ततमाय च ||96
>   ||
>
> AghorGhorRupaya GhorGhorTaraya cha | Namah Shivaya Shantaaya Namah
>   ShataTamaya cha ||
>
> P. 320  Salutations to thee that art amiable, and that art frightful,
>   and that art exceedingly so. Salutations to thee that art auspicious,
>   that art tranquil, and that art most tranquil.
>
> ---
>
> सहस्त्रोदयतशुलाय सहस्त्रनयनाय च  |
>  नमो बालार्कवर्णाय बालरूपधराय च
>   || 104 ||
>
> P. 321 Salutations to thee that hast a thousand heads and a thousand
>   feet-, to thee that hast a thousand tridents uplifted in thy hands,
>   and a thousand eyes! Salutations to thee that art of the form of the
>   rising Sun, and that art of the form of a child, that art the
>   protector of attendants all of whom are of the form of children.

---

And here is one mantra from [**Shiva  aahvaan stotra.**](http://doshidhrumit.blogspot.com/2018/05/shiv-aavahan-mantra-lyrics.html) By reciting this  mantra, One can surpass even the  death by grace of Lord Shiva.

> ॐ मृत्युंजय परेशान जगदाभयनाशन । तव ध्यानेन देवेश मृत्युप्राप्नोति
>   जीवती ।। 
> वन्दे ईशान देवाय नमस्तस्मै पिनाकिने । आदिमध्यांत रूपाय
>   मृत्युनाशं करोतु मे ।। 
> नमस्तस्मै भगवते कैलासाचल वासिने ।
>   नमोब्रह्मेन्द्र रूपाय मृत्युनाशं करोतु मे ।।
>
> Om mrityunjay pareshaan jagadaabhayanaashan Tav dhyaanen devesh
>   mrityupraapnoti jeevati
>  Vande ishaan devaay namastasmai pinakine
>   Aadimadhyaant rupaay mrityunaasham karotu me
> Namastasmai bhagwate
>   kailasachal vaasine Namobrahmendra rupaay mrityunaasham karotu me

---

And last but not least here is a similar [**dynamic Lord Shiva mantra**](http://aumamen.com/stotra/mrityunjaya-rudraya-neelakanthaya-lyrics-meaning)

> मृत्युञ्जयाय रुद्राय नीलकन्ताय शंभवे |
>  अमृतेषाय सर्वाय महादेवाय ते
>   नमः ||
>
> Mrutyunjayaaya Rudraaya Neelakantaya Shambhave 
>  Amriteshaaya
>   Sarvaaya Mahadevaaya Te Namaha”
>
> Meaning : ‘Oh Lord Shiva, you are the one who has conquered death and
>   are responsible for destruction of the Universe to let life again
>   prevail on earth. Oh lord, you are Neelkantha as you have a blue
>   throat. We pay obeisance to you lord with are hands folded in
>   namaskar.’
>
> [**2**](https://www.templepurohit.com/mantras-slokas-stotras/shiva-mantras/)

Comment: from where did the last shloka was taken? I want to know. @SwiftPushkar

Comment: @aniketkumarsingh- Oh , do you mean from which scripture or text. I think that is a kind of independent composition.But i will try to search whether they are taken from Scripture or not?

Answer (score 0):

Read [Shiva Sahasranama (Rudrayamala Tantra)](http://www.shri-yoga-devi.org/textos/Shiva-Sahasranama-Rudrayamala-transliterado.pdf).

> sāmapriya sāmavettā sāmaga sāmagapriya |
>
> dhīrodātto mahādhīro dhairyado dhairyavardhaka || 84||